# ThisWoorkbook runtime Error 438

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA to copy and paste unique values from Sheet1 onto Sheet3. However i get the runtime error 438 when i run the VBA. 
My VBA looks like this:

```
Sub UniqueList()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim dictionary As Object
Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Activate
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Len(Cells(i, "M")) <> 0 Then
        dictionary.Add Cells(i, "M").Value, 1
    End If
Next

Sheet3.Range("a2").Resize(dictionary.Count).Value = _
Application.Transpose(dictionary.keys)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox dictionary.Count & " unique cell(s) were found and copied."

End Sub
```

The line that gets the error is:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Activate
```

I run the VBA using a button from Sheet3. But i also tried running it using AltF8 and AltF11 with sheet1 open, nothing works.

Im not really sure why i get that error so i hope that there is a person who can help with a solution

Comment: The way the code is written, you can simply delete the `ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Activate` line. It's not necessary to `Activate` a sheet to work with its member objects. It is best practice however, to qualify the objects you are working with. For example, change `Cells(i, "M")` to `Sheet3.Cells(i, "M")`. Use of `Sheet1` and `Sheet1` assume VBA sheet object name, which is different syntax than `Worksheets("Sheet1`")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sheet1` isn't a member of `ThisWorkbook`. `ThisWorkbook` is a `Workbook` instance, and `Workbook` objects don't expose "dynamic members" for every worksheet in their `Worksheets` collection. Hence error 438, *Object does not support property or method*.

`Sheet1` is [I presume] the `CodeName` of a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook`: it's a global-scope `Worksheet` object VBA conveniently creates, named after the `(Name)` property of the document module.

That `Sheet1` object has a `Parent` property; like every `Worksheet` object, it *already* knows what `Workbook` instance it belongs to:

```
Debug.Print Sheet1.Parent Is ThisWorkbook
```

IntelliSense has been trying to tell you that (by *not* listing a `Sheet1` member) - listen to what it says!

---

That said, fixing the instruction like this:

```
Sheet1.Activate
```

...doesn't solve *the other problem*: you're using `Activate` only so that the unqualified `Cells` calls can refer to that specific worksheet:

> ```
> For i = 1 To lastrow
>     If Len(Cells(i, "M")) <> 0 Then
>         dictionary.Add Cells(i, "M").Value, 1
>     End If
> Next
> ```

Instead, *qualify them*:

```
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Len(Sheet1.Cells(i, "M")) <> 0 Then
        dictionary.Add Sheet1.Cells(i, "M").Value, 1
    End If
Next
```

And then the `Activate` call becomes completely useless.

These implicit `ActiveSheet` references can be easy to introduce, and hard to spot. [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an open-source VBE add-in project I manage) can help you locate them (and other things):

[image: "Implicit reference to ActiveSheet" inspection results]

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the help both of you! Using set sht=ThisWorkbook and removing activate solved the problems! :)