# Why will this not Autofill?

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a VLOOKUP from a closed workbook. I am using this With statement for it. The first line after the with works. I get the cell from the closed workbook. and it shows up on my open one. The next line where it needs to autofill all the way down does NOT work. It throws an error

"Run time error '1004'. Autofill method of Range class failed."

But if I hit debug and go to the sheet where this is supposed to get auto filled, then hit F8 to continue on and see if it works again, it then works!

So why will this work when I am on the sheet but won't when I am not on the sheet even though the first line works?

```
With MainWindow.Sheets(1)
    .Range("AE2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($B2,'" & X & "]" & shtName & "'!$B$2:$K$99999,6,FALSE)"
    .Range("AE2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AE2:AE" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Comment: your destination isn't a fully qualified range.  You're trying to autofill the currently selected sheet and not the sheet in your "With" statement.

Comment: Implicit `ActiveSheet` references are a plague. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46324415/1188513) helps.

Comment: @sous2817 Oh come on! Then what is the freaking with statement for!? grrr. I also had to then specify it for the the range for the rows count. but it works now! thanks for the help!

Comment: the main thing is you got it working and learned a bit more about  the 'With' statement.  Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: RE *I also had to then specify it for the the range for the rows count* - a dot would have sufficed to qualify the member call with the `With` block variable...

Comment: Ah interesting. Thanks for the tip. A lot of times I find these example code bits and they say they work for them but then don't for me. Maybe they don't actually work sometimes. I am getting better though haha.