# Issue with taking a number and searching for it in another form

Tags: vba, excel

I am attemping to ask for a employee id number then searching another form to find this employee. I know for a fact that my Mail_Alert works and PN is copying the number over but it is not detecting the side of the other form.

```
Sub Find_Employee()
    Dim PN As String
    PN = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "B").Value
    Range("B2") = PN
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate
    Range("C2").Activate
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
        If ActiveCell.Value = "PN" Then
        Call Mail_Alert
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `ActiveCell.Value = "PN"` with `ActiveCell.Value = PN`

Comment: Also [avoid Select and Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513), and [watch for implicit ActiveSheet references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46324415/1188513).

Comment: Thank you Victor K that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim PN As String
```

Here `PN` is a variable, a programmatic *symbol*.

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "PN" Then
```

Here `"PN"` is a string literal, a *value* that a *symbol* can have, like `ActiveCell.Value` can. But the condition probably means to verify whether `ActiveCell.Value` matches whatever `PN` (the variable) contains, not `"PN"` (the literal value).

In VBA double quotes denote string literals. Remove them.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I fix the errors I did because I didn't check the code carefully...by speed to post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please make your Code better, don't Use Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_Employee()

Dim PN As String
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = Worksheets("sheet4")

PN = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "B").Value
Range("B2") = PN

With sh

Do Until IsEmpty(.Range("C2").Value)

    If .Range("C2").Value = PN Then
    Call Mail_Alert
    End If


Loop

  .Activate 'activate sheet because wants to select Range("C2").Offset(1, 0) for some reason

Range("C2").Offset(1, 0).Select

End With






End Sub
```